# find numbers in parentheses and round them

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a file called tables.tex (lots of tables formatted for tex, including a preamble) with lines like this:

```
some words (xyz, abc) & 0.00071 (0.07846) & 0.00411 (-0.13542) \\
some more words (1) & 0.00341 (-0.59991) & 0.00001 (0.99453) \\
```

I need to find all the numbers in parentheses that are not before the first '&' in a line that ends with a double backslash and replace them with a rounded version, rounded to 3 digits. So my output at the two lines above would look like this:

```
some words (xyz, abc) & 0.00071 (0.078) & 0.00411 (-0.135) \\
some more words (1) & 0.00341 (-0.600) & 0.00001 (0.995) \\
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? I have found answers on this site that describe how to do certain pieces of this operation in various ways (round numbers, print numbers in parentheses, awk, perl, etc), but I'm having trouble putting it all together in good (actually working) style.

Answer (score 3):

Awk or Perl would be good tools for this job. Perl is easier thanks to its construct to apply arbitrary code to a regular expression match.

```
perl -pe '
    if (s/^([^&]*&)//) {             # if there's a &, then strip the prefix…
        print $1;                    # and print it
        s[\((-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)\)]    # replace decimal numbers in parentheses…
         [sprintf("(%.3f)",$&)]eg    # …by their rounding
    }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
. 4<<HERE /dev/fd/4
    echo "$(sed -rn '/\\\\/{:l;s/([^&]*&.*\()([-0-9.]*)(\).*)/\
        "\1$(printf "%.3f" "\2" )\3"/;tl;p;}'<<\SED
    some words (xyz, abc) & 0.00071 (0.07846) & 0.00411 (-0.13542) \\
    some more words (1) & 0.00341 (-0.59991) & 0.00001 (0.99453) \\ 
    SED
    )"
HERE
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
some words (xyz, abc) & 0.00071 (0.078) & 0.00411 (-0.135) \\
some more words (1) & 0.00341 (-0.600) & 0.00001 (0.995) \\
```

Apparently this is very similar to @Gilles's answer - which I'm just now realizing - in that we both use *`printf`* to get the rounding done. I guess it's probably a given in that case though, since that's sort of what it does. Of course this uses only shell constructs and *`sed`* to realize the same goal, but if the tools he recommends are available to you they're probably faster.

There is one notable exception to the similarity in our logic here though. This uses a branch test - and hence requires GNU *`sed`* - to recurse over the string to find possible misses. Gilles prints out and strips the unused portion of the string before searching at all, which is likely faster. If I had to choose between using the two, I would go with his. Still, I believe this answer stands enough on its own right to remain.